# Sort json object laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have two merged queries and I need to sort (orderBy) by id.

```
$query1= DB::table('contract')->where('to_user_id',$to_user_id)->get();
$query2= DB::table('contract')->where('from_user_id',$to_user_id)->get();
$query1= $query1->merge($query2);
```

I tried to orderBy('id') but it ordered individualy not together.

Comment: have a look on [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/merge-and-sort-array-collection)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of performing 2 queries and merging them, would it be better to just pull the relevant records in 1 go?

For example:

```
$query1= DB::table('contract')
        ->where('to_user_id',$to_user_id)
        ->orWhere('from_user_id', $to_user_id)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) to sort the collection and [values()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-values) method to reset the keys to `consecutively` numbered indexes -

```
$query1 = $query1->merge($query2);
$query1 = $query1->sortBy('id');

$query1 = $query1->values()->all();
```